# Using Opencv. How can i increment the size of an image filling the new pixels with black(0)?

Tags: opencv, resize, fill

An image has a size(50,70) but I would like to **enlarge the dimension** to size(100,100) filling the rest of the space with black color. Any suggestions working in opencv? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`copyMakeBorder` is the way to go: [CopyMakeBorder (OpenCV 3.1)](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga2ac1049c2c3dd25c2b41bffe17658a36). You have to specify the number of pixels on each side to add (top, bottom, left, right).

```
Mat img = Matrix::ones(Size(50, 70), CV_8UC1) * 255;
Mat img_large;
copyMakeBorder(img, img_large, 15, 15, 25, 25, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar::all(0));
imshow("img", img);
imshow("img_large", img_large);
waitKey();
```

Comment: @Miki: Thanks for the hint. It should be ``imshow`` of course.

Comment: @J.Gastón T.I. Does my solution fit your problem?